# Reusing same labels across different chapters

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing my thesis which uses `classicthesis.sty` style. The thesis brings together a collection of papers and put them as individual chapters (all the chapters are included in `main.tex`). Some of the labels for figures, sections, tables etc. in two or more papers are the same and putting them together causes a problem. I would like to find a clean way of resolving this problem.

Comment: See an update here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346712/reusing-same-figure-table-and-equation-labels-across-different-chapters

Answer (score 10):

Based on the assumption that each of the `\ref`s inside a paper only refers to `\label`s inside the paper itself, you can introduce `\label` prefixes that should make the references unique:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{% ...if you're using hyperref
  \let\oldlabel\label% Copy original version of \label
  \let\oldref\ref% Copy original version of \ref
}

\newcommand{\addlabelprefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1-##1}}% Update \label
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1-##1}}% Update \ref
}
\newcommand{\removelabelprefix}{%
  \renewcommand{\label}{\oldlabel}% Restore \label
  \renewcommand{\ref}{\oldref}% Restore \ref
}

\begin{document}

% Hypothetical first paper

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
See section~\ref{sec:section}.

% Hypothetical second paper

\addlabelprefix{test}
\section{Another section}\label{sec:section}
See section~\ref{sec:section}.

\end{document}‎
```

Note that the references work as expected despite the same label `sec:section`.

Comment: Hi Werner, Many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the solution did not work for me. I am using a custom thesis style (classicthesis) from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/, and the document class is scrreprt. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @Bishoksan: [`classicthesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) uses [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), which in turn redefines the way `\label` and `\ref` works. So, you'll have to delay the storing of `\oldlabel` and `\oldref` until `\AtBeginDocument`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: sorry to tell you that it still does not work. I have the following content in my main.tex now. I seriously cannot figure out what could be the problem. Could you help? Thanks

Comment: \documentclass{scrreprt}               
                
\input{classicthesis-config}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldlabel\label
  \let\oldref\ref
}

\newcommand{\addlabelprefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1-##1}}
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1-##1}}
}
\newcommand{\removelabelprefix}{%
  \renewcommand{\label}{\oldlabel}
  \renewcommand{\ref}{\oldref}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain} 
\include{Chapters/1/Chapter01} 
\include{Chapters/2/Chapter02} 
\end{document}

Comment: @Bishoksan: You need to place `\addlabelprefix{blah}` before `\include{Chapters/2/Chapter02}` which should add `blah` in front of *every* `\label` and `\ref` used in the second chapter.