# Reusing same figure, table, and equation labels across different chapters

Tags: cross-referencing

For my thesis I use the memoir class and the `\include` command to include all the chapters. Unfortunately, I used identical figure and table labels in some chapters. Therefore, the labelling is totally off.

I found this solution to my problem:

[Reusing same labels across different chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311975/reusing-same-labels-across-different-chapters/346698#346698)

Following Werner's initial advice and his last command (May 30 '16 at 14:19), I managed to fix the figure and tables labels. But now the equation labels are off (i.e., `equation` ??) is displayed whenever I refer to an equation).

Here is part of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\AtBeginDocument{% ...if you're using hyperref
  \let\oldlabel\label% Copy original version of \label
  \let\oldref\ref% Copy original version of \ref
}

\newcommand{\addlabelprefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1-##1}}% Update \label
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1-##1}}% Update \ref
}
\newcommand{\removelabelprefix}{%
  \renewcommand{\label}{\oldlabel}% Restore \label
  \renewcommand{\ref}{\oldref}% Restore \ref
}

\addlabelprefix{a}
\include{chapter1}
```

Any advice on how to fix this issue is welcome!

Comment: Please show us your version of the code, with `memoir`

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

Comment: No, the document ...

Comment: The document is only a fragment yet

Comment: Please post a compilable document, with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document} ...\end{document}`, not only fragments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the frame of [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311975/reusing-same-labels-across-different-chapters/346698#346698) above, but apply a different method:

- Each time a \chapter starts, a auxiliary counter is increased and a `\@currentprefix` is defined, as `chapter::\number\value{auxchapter}`
- This `\@currentprefix` serves in renewed versions of `\label` and `\ref` as `\@currentprefix::#1` (hidden in `\generatemultilabel`.

References in and from `\include{foochapter}` will work too then.

Additionally, I defined a macro to make references across chapters with the relevant chapter number and usual label.

The current approach works for `book` as well as for `memoir`.

It will fail if `cleveref` is used, due to the optional argument of `\label` introduced in `cleveref`.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{externalchapter.tex}
\chapter{Yet another nice chapter}\label{foochapter}
See chapter~\ref{foochapter}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}\label{foofigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Foo table}\label{footable}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^{2} \label{einstein}
\end{equation}

See \ref{einstein} or \ref{footable} or \ref{foofigure}
\end{filecontents}

\newcounter{auxchapter}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\generatemultilabel}[1]{%
  \@currentprefix::#1%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\latex@@label\label
  \let\latex@@ref\ref

  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
    \latex@@label{\generatemultilabel{#1}}%
  }
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
    \latex@@ref{\generatemultilabel{#1}}%
  }

  \xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
    \stepcounter{auxchapter}%
    \edef\@currentprefix{chapter::\number\value{auxchapter}}
  }{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}

  \newcommand{\crosschapterref}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \edef\@currentprefix{chapter::#1}%
    \ref{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }
}
\makeatother





\begin{document}

% Hypothetical first paper

\chapter{A chapter}\label{foochapter}
See chapter~\ref{foochapter}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}\label{foofigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Foo table}\label{footable}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^{2} \label{einstein}
\end{equation}

See \ref{einstein} or \ref{footable} or \ref{foofigure}

% Hypothetical second paper

\chapter{Another chapter}\label{foochapter}
See chapter~\ref{foochapter}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}\label{foofigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Foo table}\label{footable}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^{2} \label{einstein}
\end{equation}

See \ref{einstein} or \ref{footable} or \ref{foofigure}

\include{externalchapter}

But in \crosschapterref{1}{einstein} we saw

\end{document}‎
```

[image]

Comment: This worked well for me after some modifications.

Added `\renewcommand{\ltx@label}[1]{\latex@@label{\generatemultilabel{#1}}}` for it to work with amsmath.

Added `\edef\@currentprefix{}` at the start to make it work before the first \chapter.

Comment: @Forss: Yes, but the question was not for `amsmath`